# Why not extend CordovaActivity when embedding CordovaWebView?

Tags: cordova

There is a Cordova Guide "Embedding Cordova WebView on Android"
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20Android

Can anybody please explain why this guide advises to write the class having the form:
public class CordovaViewTestActivity extends Activity implements CordovaInterface {

instead of:
public class CordovaViewTestActivity extends CordovaActivity {

Thanks,
DM

---

More information:

1. The guide advice seems to risk me accidentally failing to cut/paste many behaviors that the CordovaActivity is already dealing with.
2. It is also different to the way an activity looks if created using create.js. e.g.
   public class test extends DroidGap {
3. It also seems to contradict the comment in the CordovaActivity class which says:
   This class is the main Android activity that represents the Cordova
   application.  It should be extended by the user to load the specific
   html file that contains the application.

Comment: Just wondered the same thing myself. Did you try implementing it in the way you suggested? Did it work for you?

Comment: It's actually vital. I should not have to extend it because I need things to happened outside of cordova. If I'm *embedded* cordova, it means I have an app that has a cordova *component*, but if I *must* extend the activity, then it's not a component.

Answer (score 0):

One of the authors makes a few arguments against extending CordovaActivity here: 
http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@cordova.apache.org/msg08771.html

> Because there are things CordovaActivity does that you may not want,
>   also there is no such thing as dual inheritance in Java.
>
> For example if you have a MapActivity you can implement a
>   CordovaInterface, but not extend a CordovaActivity.
>
> Also, we haven't fully tested the use case where one extends the
>   CordovaActivity, so there's that as well.

Comment: What about adding overrides of native events inside of a custom plugin? I am trying to know where the volumes buttons are pressed and I know that I have to add the override to a class that extends from the Activity but I can't do that in a custom plugin, or can I? I need a custom plugin cause that will be added later in an appbuilder/Telerik app. Thank you.

Comment: The cordovan build actually falls because you don't extends it with:

    Error: No Java files found which extend CordovaActivity.

This is very annoying. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The cordovan build actually falls because you don't extends it with:

```
Error: No Java files found which extend CordovaActivity.
```

This is very annoying.

See the solution here:
[Upgrading from Cordova 2.5 to Cordova 3.0 , facing issue while using CordovaInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354846/upgrading-from-cordova-2-5-to-cordova-3-0-facing-issue-while-using-cordovainte)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after renaming the default Cordova config and package names. I fixed it by doing the following:

cordova platform remove android

cordova platform add android